# In ADF I am getting an error - there is already an object names sqldb in database

Tags: t-sql, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I have to write the foldername and the count of files in folder in sqldb.

I wrote this statement inside the lookup activity

```
create table dbo.sqldb12(name char(20), count int),

insert into sqldb12 
values ('@{item().name}', @{int(activity('Filter1').output.ItemsCount)})

select * from sqldb12
```

`item().name` is the output of foreach activity which is basically a foldernames

`(activity('Filter1').output.ItemsCount` -- this activity will return the counts

Do you know why I am getting this error?

Comment: What is the specific error?   Count is a reserved word so give the column a better name - count of what?  eg fileCount or countOfFiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory.
Since you are running the look up activity within for iteration, the create table query on 1st iteration would create a table but in subsequent iterations would throw an error stating it already exists

Comment: correct then how can i create the table at runtime?

Comment: Still not sure why you want to create the table at runtime but you can validate whether the table exists prior to making anew one again :

IF EXISTS (
 SELECT * 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '' 
 AND  TABLE_NAME = ''
)